# ASP.Net MVC data annotation [Required] automate i18n validation messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internationalization

I am currently working through a large software solution in ASP.NET MVC and am implementing i18n. I have heard there may be a way to automate i18n validation messages for data annotations.  For example, given the code:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "VMAccountConfirmPassword", ResourceType = typeof(R))]
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceName = "VMAccountErrConfirmPassword", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(R))]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

I would love it if it was possible that all error messages generated by the [Required] data annotation would be internationalized. Without me having to add custom error messages for everything.

Is this possible?

Kind Regards,
Leigh Cooper